# Serial Number in logical order without gaps

Tags: t-sql, sql-order-by, rank, partition

I'm trying to generate a serial number based on a few conditions.
My dataset:

```
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
| Client | Start_Date |  End_date  | Product | Ser_No |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
|   44   | 22-01-2018 | 31-12-2018 |    A    |        |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
|   44   | 24-02-2018 | 01-01-2019 |    B    |        |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
|   44   | 12-03-2018 | 01-01-2019 |    C    |        |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
|   100  | 24-01-2018 | 30-11-2018 |    A    |        |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
|   100  | 26-01-2018 | 15-12-2018 |    D    |        |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
|   100  | 26-01-2018 | 01-02-2019 |    E    |        |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
|   100  | 01-03-2018 | 31-01-2019 |    F    |        |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
```

What I did to configure my serial number:

```
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Client ORDER BY Client, Start_date ASC)
```

So now it generates a serial number for my which looks like this:

```
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
| Client | Start_Date |  End_date  | Product | Ser_No |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
|   44   | 22-01-2018 | 31-12-2018 |    A    |    1   |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
|   44   | 24-02-2018 | 01-01-2019 |    B    |    2   |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
|   44   | 12-03-2018 | 01-01-2019 |    C    |    3   |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
|   100  | 24-01-2018 | 30-11-2018 |    A    |    1   |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
|   100  | 26-01-2018 | 15-12-2018 |    D    |    2   |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
|   100  | 26-01-2018 | 01-02-2019 |    E    |    2   |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
|   100  | 01-03-2018 | 31-01-2019 |    F    |    4   |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
```

What goes wrong for my analysis is the last line, it generates the serial number. What it has to be is 3.
Can anayone help me to generate it in this order?
Thanks in advance!

**Extra**
In addition to my question from yesterday, there is something extra that I need to do. Because the Ser_No has to be the same when my Start_Date is the same, but the Ser_No has also be the same when my folowing records is the same product (also when it has a different Start_Date)

So what I I expect and what I get right now:

```
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+------------+
| Client | Start_Date |  End_date  | Product | Ser_No | Ser_No New |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+------------+
|   44   | 22-01-2018 | 31-12-2018 |    A    |    1   |      1     |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+------------+
|   44   | 24-02-2018 | 01-01-2019 |    B    |    2   |      2     |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+------------+
|   44   | 12-03-2018 | 01-01-2019 |    C    |    2   |      2     |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+------------+
|   100  | 24-01-2018 | 30-11-2018 |    A    |    1   |      1     |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+------------+
|   100  | 26-01-2018 | 15-12-2018 |    D    |    2   |      2     |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+------------+
|   100  | 26-01-2018 | 01-02-2019 |    E    |    2   |      2     |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+------------+
|   100  | 01-03-2018 | 31-01-2019 |    F    |    3   |      3     |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+------------+
|   100  | 11-04-2018 | 31-03-2019 |    F    |    4   |      3     |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+------------+
|   100  | 20-04-2018 | 31-01-2019 |    G    |    5   |      4     |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+------------+
|   100  | 21-04-2018 | 31-01-2019 |    A    |    6   |      5     |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+------------+
|   100  | 21-04-2018 | 31-01-2019 |    B    |    6   |      5     |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+------------+
|   100  | 01-05-2018 | 31-01-2019 |    B    |    7   |      5     |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+--------+------------+
```

Any idea on how to achieve this, because I won't get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`DENSE_RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead:

> This function returns the rank of each row within a result set partition, **with no gaps** in the ranking values.

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Client ORDER BY Start_date) AS Ser_no
```

Additionaly the `Client` in `ORDER BY` has no effect because it has the same value per partition.

Comment: Wauw was it that easy, thanks. Ah I didn't know about the order by, thanks for the tip

Comment: It's good that you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.